# Using column name pattern to create new variables in a list

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I am trying to reduce 33 variables to a single indicator using the following code (I know it is extremely inefficient:

```
data_indicator <- data %>%
  mutate(plot_1=(farm_sell_1+farm_lease_1+farm_bequeath_1)/3, na.rm=T) %>%
  mutate(plot_sec_1=ifelse(plot_1>.5, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(plot_2=(farm_sell_2+farm_lease_2+farm_bequeath_2)/3, na.rm=T) %>%
  mutate(plot_sec_2=ifelse(plot_2>.5, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(plot_3=(farm_sell_3+farm_lease_3+farm_bequeath_3)/3, na.rm=T) %>%
  mutate(plot_sec_3=ifelse(plot_3>.5, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(plot_4=(farm_sell_4+farm_lease_4+farm_bequeath_4)/3, na.rm=T) %>%
  mutate(plot_sec_4=ifelse(plot_4>.5, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(plot_5=(farm_sell_5+farm_lease_5+farm_bequeath_5)/3, na.rm=T) %>%
  mutate(plot_sec_5=ifelse(plot_5>.5, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(plot_6=(farm_sell_6+farm_lease_6+farm_bequeath_6)/3, na.rm=T) %>%
  mutate(plot_sec_6=ifelse(plot_6>.5, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(plot_7=(farm_sell_7+farm_lease_7+farm_bequeath_7)/3, na.rm=T) %>%
  mutate(plot_sec_7=ifelse(plot_7>.5, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(plot_8=(farm_sell_8+farm_lease_8+farm_bequeath_8)/3, na.rm=T) %>%
  mutate(plot_sec_8=ifelse(plot_8>.5, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(plot_9=(farm_sell_9+farm_lease_9+farm_bequeath_9)/3, na.rm=T) %>%
  mutate(plot_sec_9=ifelse(plot_9>.5, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(plot_10=(farm_sell_10+farm_lease_10+farm_bequeath_10)/3, na.rm=T) %>%
  mutate(plot_sec_10=ifelse(plot_10>.5, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(plot_11=(farm_sell_11+farm_lease_11+farm_bequeath_11)/3, na.rm=T) %>%
  mutate(plot_sec_11=ifelse(plot_11>.5, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(num_plots_sec = plot_sec_1+plot_sec_2+plot_sec_3+plot_sec_4+plot_sec_5+plot_sec_6+plot_sec_7+plot_sec_8+plot_sec_9+plot_sec_10+plot_sec_11, na.rm=T)
```

How could I loop through these 11 variables such that I get a measure for each variable that ends in a particular number "_1" and then sum from 1:11 those numbers to get 1 indicator?

How do I loop through all the variables that end in a number, sum them together to create a new variable that ends in a number, and then sum all eleven of those variables together into a single indicator?

Example of current data frame:

```
$ farm_sell_1      <dbl+lbl> 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,...
$ farm_sell_2      <dbl> 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, NA, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, N...
$ farm_sell_3      <dbl> 0, 1, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, 1, NA, 1, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA,...
$ farm_sell_4      <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, ...
$ farm_sell_5      <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA...
$ farm_sell_6      <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA...
$ farm_sell_7      <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA...
$ farm_sell_8      <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, N...
$ farm_sell_9      <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, N...
$ farm_sell_10     <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, N...
$ farm_sell_11     <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, N...
$ farm_lease_1     <dbl+lbl> 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,...
$ farm_lease_2     <dbl> 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, NA, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, N...
$ farm_lease_3     <dbl> 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, 1, NA, 1, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA,...
$ farm_lease_4     <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, ...
$ farm_lease_5     <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA...
$ farm_lease_6     <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA...
$ farm_lease_7     <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA...
$ farm_lease_8     <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, N...
$ farm_lease_9     <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, N...
$ farm_lease_10    <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, N...
$ farm_lease_11    <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, N...
$ farm_bequeath_1  <dbl+lbl> 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,...
$ farm_bequeath_2  <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, N...
$ farm_bequeath_3  <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA,...
$ farm_bequeath_4  <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, ...
$ farm_bequeath_5  <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA...
$ farm_bequeath_6  <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA...
$ farm_bequeath_7  <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA...
$ farm_bequeath_8  <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, N...
$ farm_bequeath_9  <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, N...
$ farm_bequeath_10 <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, N...
$ farm_bequeath_11 <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, N...
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to make this a bit cleaner is to switch this data into long data. For more info on wide vs. long check out this site: https://uc-r.github.io/tidyr

I'll go through this step by step so you can see how it works, and then include on bit of code that does it all at once in the end.

First some fake data to use:

```
fake.data <- data.frame(matrix(data = rbinom(1650, 1, 0.5), nrow = 50, ncol = 33))
colnames(fake.data) <- c(paste0("farm_sell_", 1:11), paste0("farm_lease_", 1:11),
                          paste0("farm_bequeath_", 1:11))
```

It looks like yours above:

```
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  33 variables:
 $ farm_sell_1     : int  0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 ...
 $ farm_sell_2     : int  0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 ...
 $ farm_sell_3     : int  1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ farm_sell_4     : int  1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 ...
 $ farm_sell_5     : int  1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 ...
 $ farm_sell_6     : int  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ farm_sell_7     : int  1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 ...
 $ farm_sell_8     : int  0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 ...
 $ farm_sell_9     : int  1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ farm_sell_10    : int  1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 ...
 $ farm_sell_11    : int  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ farm_lease_1    : int  0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 ...
 $ farm_lease_2    : int  0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 ...
 $ farm_lease_3    : int  0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 ...
 $ farm_lease_4    : int  1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ farm_lease_5    : int  0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 ...
 $ farm_lease_6    : int  0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 ...
 $ farm_lease_7    : int  0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ farm_lease_8    : int  0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 ...
 $ farm_lease_9    : int  0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 ...
 $ farm_lease_10   : int  1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 ...
 $ farm_lease_11   : int  1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 ...
 $ farm_bequeath_1 : int  1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 ...
 $ farm_bequeath_2 : int  0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ farm_bequeath_3 : int  1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 ...
 $ farm_bequeath_4 : int  0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ farm_bequeath_5 : int  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 ...
 $ farm_bequeath_6 : int  0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 ...
 $ farm_bequeath_7 : int  0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 ...
 $ farm_bequeath_8 : int  0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ farm_bequeath_9 : int  0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 ...
 $ farm_bequeath_10: int  0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 ...
 $ farm_bequeath_11: int  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

You'll need the `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages to do all of this.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
```

Then we make it long using `pivot_longer` from `tidyr`. I have added a key here to reference which farm each indicator is for. We will need it later to group over, but basically matches the row number from your original data.

```
data.long <- fake.data %>%
  #add a key to keep track of stuff
  mutate(farm_key = 1:n()) %>%
  pivot_longer(farm_sell_1:farm_bequeath_11, names_to = "variable", values_to = "value")
```

This looks like this

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  farm_key variable    value
     <int> <chr>       <int>
1        1 farm_sell_1     0
2        1 farm_sell_2     0
3        1 farm_sell_3     1
4        1 farm_sell_4     1
```

Next, we use `separate` to split your farm_sell_1 etc. variables into something more machine readable:

```
data.long2 <- data.long %>%
  tidyr::separate(col = variable, into = c("farm", "var", "var_num"), sep = "_")
```

Results in data like this:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  farm_key farm  var   var_num value
     <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <int>
1        1 farm  sell  1           0
2        1 farm  sell  2           0
3        1 farm  sell  3           1
4        1 farm  sell  4           1
```

Then we do all of the addition you were doing above. First, we group by var_num and add those variables for each farm. This is the same as adding farm_sell_1 + farm_lease_1 + farm_bequeath_1 and dividing by three, like you did above. Then we calculate the plot_sec via the `ifelse` statement. Finally, we can add up those 11 indices (one for each _1, _2, _3) for each farm, resulting in one index value per farm.

```
data.long3 <- data.long2 %>%
  group_by(farm_key, var_num) %>%
  summarise(plot_val = sum(value, na.rm = T)/3) %>% #same as plot_1, plot_2, etc.
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(plot_sec = ifelse(plot_val>0.5,1,0)) %>%
  #sum together to get one value for each farm_key
  group_by(farm_key) %>%
  summarise(num_plots_sec = sum(plot_sec)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Then the data looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  farm_key num_plots_sec
     <int>         <dbl>
1        1             4
2        2             4
3        3             4
4        4             8
5        5             7
```

And as promised, a chunk of code to do this all at once:

```
data.one.ind <- fake.data %>%
  #add a key to keep track of stuff
  mutate(farm_key = 1:n()) %>%
  pivot_longer(farm_sell_1:farm_bequeath_11, names_to = "variable", values_to = "value") %>%
  tidyr::separate(col = variable, into = c("farm", "var", "var_num"), sep = "_") %>%
  group_by(farm_key, var_num) %>%
  summarise(plot_val = sum(value, na.rm = T)/3) %>% #same as plot_1, plot_2, etc.
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(plot_sec = ifelse(plot_val>0.5,1,0)) %>%
  #sum together to get one value for each farm_key
  group_by(farm_key) %>%
  summarise(num_plots_sec = sum(plot_sec)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

All in all, it probably doesn't actually save you too much typing. But it is much more adaptable to changes in variables.